# conformal map from a disk minus a radial segment to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I need to find a conformal map from the disk minus a radial segment $\Omega$ to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, where
$\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1, z \notin [\frac{1}{2},1) \}$.

I have tried looking at rotations, exponential maps and mobius transforms, but non of these give the required mapping.

Comment: *Hint:* Start with a Möbius transformation which maps the unit disk onto itself, and $1/2$ to $0$.

Comment: @Martin R, $w=\frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{z}{2}}$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you continue now?

Comment: @MartinR, not sure!